# орфография "неумелый"

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Почему "неумелый" пишется слитно?

Answer (score 3):

*Неумелый* — это тот, кто не способен что-либо делать. Можно ведь подобрать несколько синонимов, например слово *бездарный*. Согласно правилам орфографии, если подобрать синонимы без НЕ представляется возможным, слово пишется слитно.